# fortran makefile with an ordered list of source files

Tags: makefile, fortran

I am trying to create a makefile that will compile source files in a specific order. I have the source file names ordered in a .txt file.

```
1 # compiler
2 FC = gfortran
3 # compile flags
4 FCFLAGS = -g -fbounds-check
5 FCFLAGS = -O2
6 # required for gfortran
7 FCFLAGS += -I/usr/include
8 # source files and objects
9 #SRCS = $(patsubst %.mod, %.o)
10 
11 # program name
12 PROGRAM = madeIt
13 
14 all: $(PROGRAM)
15 
16 $(PROGRAM): $(SRCS)
17     $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^
18 
19 
20 clean: 
21     rm  *.o *.mod
```

I created a shell script to compile them in order, and then try to link them via the makefile, but I'm not sure that is the best way to go.

```
1 #usr/bin/sh
2 
3 # initial cleanup
4 rm *.o *.mod
5 rm oCommand.txt
6 rm oFiles.txt
7 
8 for line in $(cat order.txt); do gfortran -c "$line"; done
9 
10 ls *.o > oFiles.txt
11 
12 for line in $(cat oFiles.txt); do echo -n "$line" >> oCommand.txt; echo -n "
13 
14 cat oFiles.txt | wc -l
15 
16 for i in $(cat oCommand.txt); do gfortran -o madeIt "$i"; done
```

Any thoughts? 
I'm pretty lost here, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Forget the shell script, and use a tool such as makedepf90 to generate a makefile snippet specifying the dependencies so that make knows in which order files must be compiled.

If you use GNU make, you can then include that snippet into your main makefile, otherwise copy-paste or something like that.

Comment: cmake might also be an alternative, it can handle fortran module dependencies.